# Combine users social feeds

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking

I'm trying to figure out a way of displaying my user's personal social feeds on my site.

I know an application will have to be made to use the API etc, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to display the users personal feeds. Here's an example of how I'd like it to work:

User clicks to connect to Facebook/Twitter/(Other) > 
User allows authorisation of app > 
Users personal feed that they would see on Facebook or Twitter is now being shown on the site.

It has to be personalised for every user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking just for aggregators of user feeds from different social networks, you might try to give a look to http://pavelk2.github.io/social-feed/, which works with Facebook, Google+, Instagram and VK. It is open-source and you can get the code here: https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed